# Which key mechanism do Apple Magic Keyboards use?

Tags: hardware, keyboard

Apple currently has 2 different Magic Keyboards:

- [A2449 Magic Keyboard with Touch ID](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK293LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-for-mac-models-with-apple-silicon-us-english)
- [A2450 Magic Keyboard with Lock Key](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2A3LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english)

I'm trying to decide between the two. I don't necessarily need Touch ID, but I absolutely want to avoid getting [butterfly keys](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/butterfly-keyboard-vs-scissor-keyboard/).

Do both keyboards use the scissor mechanism? Are there any advantages to the A2449 model besides Touch ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magic Keyboard was introduced in 2021, which is after Apple reverted to the Scissor key design in 2019. The keys feel exactly like the laptop keys in the current M1/M2 models.

It's always worth trying one out in an Apple Store before purchase.

There's no other difference between them than TouchID. TouchID only works with Apple Silicon Macs. *(Having used TouchID on iPhones and iPads for years, I had thought that it was unnecessary and a bit of a gimmick on macOS, but I do find it a really useful time-saver, instead of typing a lengthy password all the time, while maintaining security.)*

You might want to consider getting the 'full-size' keyboard with numpad keys, better arrow keys, PageUp, etc.